# Removing unused tags in TFS2012

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, tfs-2012

Perhaps a bit anal, but when testing the tag functionality of TFS2012, I created some test tags that I'm not interested in using.

Despite removing these tags from all work items, they still show up in the "autosuggest" dropdown.  Is there any way to remove them from that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While probably not supported, I was able to do this with no obvious ill effects by going into the Tfs_{ProjectCollectionId} database and deleting the records found in tbl_TagDefinition.

Comment: tbl_PropertyValue is the table that keeps track of added or removed tags from a work item. Might need to remove those references as well.